# Simple PHP Templating With Looping

Tags: php, loops, template-engine

Hey I wrote a very simple template system for our designers to use. Its uses `str_replace` under the hood to do its thing.

Its works great! The issue now is i'd like do some looping (`foreach`) on some data passed.

Here's and example of the template code

```
$var_c = [
    [
        "head" => "a",
        "body" => "b",
        "foot" => "c"
    ],
    [
        "head" => "x",
        "body" => "y",
        "foot" => "z"
    ]
];

$tpl_vars = [ 
    "__{var_a}__",
    "__{var_b}__",
    "__{var_c}__"
];

$real_vars = [
    $var_a,
    $var_b,
    $var_c
];

str_replace($tpl_vars, $real_vars, $content_body);
```

Note `$var_c` contains an array and i'd like to loop through this array. How do i achieve that.
For structure i was thinking

```
__startloop__
 loop var_c as c
  c[head] 
  c[body]
  c[foot]
__endloop__
```

I cant seem to get my head around how to code this. :)

UPDATE: Twig, smarty and the likes are too big and cumbersome for the work. Its also introduces the learning curve for the designers to adopt a templating language.

Comment: ....why not use a templating engine like Twig? This is clearly not a learning exercise, so time is money. Build up from others' work.

Comment: @Anonymous Twig, smarty and the likes are too big and cumbersome for the work. Its also introduces the learning curve for the designers to adopt a templating language.

Comment: `<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?><!-- ... --><?php endforeach ?>`

Comment: writing your own templating engine is a stupid idea. Use Savant, it's quick, well documented and easy to use -  http://phpsavant.com/

Answer (score 1):

See my Text-Template class. It supports conditions (if), loops (for) and filters: https://github.com/dermatthes/text-template

Example template (String in a variable):

```
Hello {= name},
Your list of Items:
{for curItem in items}
{=@index1}: {= curItem.name}
{/for}
```

PHP-Code:

```
<?php
$data = [
    "name" => "Some Username",
    "items" => [
        ["name" => "First Item"],
        ["name" => "Second Item"]
    ]
];
$tt = new TextTemplate ($templateString);
echo $tt->apply ($data);
```

This should do the job.